# workflow Foundation 4.5 Side By Side versioning

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Using VS 2012 and .Net 4.5 I've developed a workflow and deployed it. Because of some business changes i had to change it. Since there's no bug on the previous version and i can let the old instances conclude i decided to use side-by-side versioning.

There's a problem though. My workflow has c# expressions. I did implemented a factory and it works only for the new instances! If a old instance get a message, the runtime returns me that the workflow (v1) is not "compiled"! Which i'm interpreting as "the service activation is working only for the latest version".

Comment: Huh?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412914/wf4-5-not-compiling-side-by-side-c-sharp-workflows

Comment: @Will i asked first... check the timestamp...

Comment: Doesn't matter; I'm not saying anything is wrong here.  Its just odd that you both have the exact same problem, you both asked around the same time, and I haven't seen any similar questions come through my WF4 feed before.  I'm assuming you guys work together and are dealing with the same issue.  You might want to combine your efforts on one question.

Comment: @Will actually no... he might have read my similar question on the MSDN forum as re-asked here... anyhow... do you have any ideas of what might be happening?

Comment: I did, but I was wrong.  I didn't think it was possible to compile C# expressions outside of visual studio, so it wouldn't be possible to load a workflow file (xaml) with C# expressions and execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up finding the same answers described here: [WF4.5 not compiling side-by-side c# workflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412914/wf4-5-not-compiling-side-by-side-c-sharp-workflows)

I had to manually force the versions on the factory...