# WF4.5 not compiling side-by-side c# workflows

Tags: c#, iis, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have an IIS hosted xamlx workflow with c# expressions that I'm trying to run in side-by-side versioning.

I did exactly like this article: [Side by side versioning of workflow services](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2012/10/11/side-by-side-versioning-of-workflow-services.aspx)

New instances of the workflow works as expected, but when I call an instance of a prior version of the workflow, it raises an error telling me that it's not compiled.

Error:

> Unable to locate the ICompiledExpressionRoot for compiled location
>   'auxData'.  Make sure that the definition for the activity containing
>   this expression has been compiled.

BTW, I have a custom factory that compiles the workflow.

```
<serviceActivations>        
    <add service="Service1.xamlx" relativeAddress="~/Service1.xamlx" factory="MyServiceHostFactory" />
</serviceActivations>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After analyzing the source code from .Net, I realized that the method CreateWorkflowServiceHost that I override in my custom workflow factory, adds all supported versions in it's return object.

All I had to do is iterate this collection and compile them all.

Final source code:

```
    protected override WorkflowServiceHost CreateWorkflowServiceHost(WorkflowService service, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        var host = base.CreateWorkflowServiceHost(service, baseAddresses);

        // add your customizations here…
        CompileExpressions(service.Body);
        foreach (var supportedVersion in host.SupportedVersions)
        {
            CompileExpressions(supportedVersion.Body);
        }

        return host;
    }
```

Comment: If you are using a xaml reader and `ActivityXamlServices.Load` then you can also set `ActivityXamlServicesSettings` property `CompileExpressions = true` in the settings parameter when loading each xaml.